# Gradle 6.1.1 in Android studio can not run app in JDK 1.8, but build assemble can run succefully

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My env:

Gradle 6.1.1 JDK in Android studio 1.8

[image]

[image]

I want to use JDK 1.8 as the gradle env, and click run button in the android studio.

[image]

It will failed by:

Cause: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

[image]

I am curious that the assemble task can run successfully in JDK 1.8. It will package the apk for me. Why the Android studio can not build this apk by click the run button?

I know I should set the gradle env as JDK 11. but I want to know the reason. Is this a bug for Android studio or I miss any information?

I delete my gradle caches files. And build it again. I got the same result.

Comment: Anyone know how to insert the image not by the link? I am a new guy in stack overfolw

Comment: Seems to be a known bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/248658503